# Show a ManyToManyField as Checkboxes in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, manytomanyfield

Is there a simple way to show a ManyToManyField as Checkboxes in Django Admin? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest changing the accepted answer, so as to not confuse visitors.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760421/django-manytomany/1760592#1760592) it seems like it is possible to use [ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) to override the ManyToManyField to use [CheckBoxSelectMultiple](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

I haven't tried it and am merely quoting from the source, but it seems plausible. Good luck.

**Warning**: as [@errx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577490/errx) rightly pointed out, the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) highlights the following caveat:

> If you want to use a **custom widget**
>   with a relation field (i.e. `ForeignKey`
>   or **ManyToManyField**), make sure you
>   haven't included that field's name in
>   `raw_id_fields` or `radio_fields`.
>
> `formfield_overrides` won't let you
>   change the widget on relation fields
>   that have `raw_id_fields` or
>   `radio_fields` set. That's because
>   `raw_id_fields` and `radio_fields` imply
>   custom widgets of their own.

Comment: there is a warning from django docs.
If you want to use a custom widget with a relation field (i.e. ForeignKey or ManyToManyField), make sure you haven't included that field's name in raw_id_fields or radio_fields.

formfield_overrides won't let you change the widget on relation fields that have raw_id_fields or radio_fields set. That's because raw_id_fields and radio_fields imply custom widgets of their own.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Will place warning in answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is most certainly possible. Here is the code which you can place in the `ModelAdmin` subclass:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'your field name':
        kwargs['widget'] = form_widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        kwargs['help_text'] = ''

    return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
```

This was derived from looking into the admin code.

Answer (score 5):

To override for a single field the following is useful:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(VNodeAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['node_type'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    return form
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no simple way to do this. You can try to override ModelAdmin class but this is not a "simple" way.

But you can use filter_horizontal or filter_vertical to add almost similar functionality

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal