# Radio Button on Many-to-Many field using Inline ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Heres the scenario :

```
class Account(model.Model):
    acc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Person(model.Model):
    accounts = models.ManyToManyField(Account)


class Message(model.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Now I am using InineModelAdmin in my `admin.py`. So it looks like this :

```
class Account(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    some code
    ...

admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)


class MessageInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Message


class PersonAdmin(admin.Modeladmin):
    inlines = [MessageInLine]


admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

So it stands that `Message` has a `ForeignKey` on `Person` and `Person` has a `Many-To-Many` with `Account`.

Now in the `Django-admin`, where I add Person it obviously gives the components of `Person` and `Message`. Now here the accounts are in a list, where they need to be selected by holding `CTRL`. I want to use a `radio_button` to allow selecting multiple buttons for faster selection. How can I do this?

Edit :

I tried using radio_field like this inside `PersonAdmin` :

```
radio_fields = {"accounts":admin.VERTICAL}
```

But it gives me an error that says that it is nether a `ForeignKey` nor does it have a `Choices Set` So obviously this isnt working. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784567/show-a-manytomanyfield-as-checkboxes-in-django-admin) seems there is a way using [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

```
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MessageInLine]
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

Please read the another question too

Comment: Just updated the question with that. I have already tried it. But thats only allowed on either a `ForeignKey` or a `Choices Set`. So I'm looking for a way around this. thanks anyways.

Comment: Wow!!! Awesome man! Kudos! 
Can you explain it a bit please? I dont get all of that. only parts of it. :0

Comment: Here is a better explanation of `formfield_overrides` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides)

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be from `django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple` ?