# manytomany field in form with checkboxes insted select field in django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have model with ManyToManyField. Now I need form but don't need select field in template.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, blank=True, null=True, related_name='foos')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

What I really need is to display all data from the Foo model with checkboxes in template, instead of select field which I have if use model.Form and {{ form }} call in template.

```
class BarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

view.py

```
def show_form(request, id):
    foo = get_object_or_404(Foo, id=id)
    form = BarForm()
    ...
```

Comment: answer searching "Many to many as checkbox" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760421/how-can-i-render-a-manytomanyfield-as-checkboxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show a `ManyToManyField` as checkboxes instead of a select field, you need to set the widget in the `Meta` class of the appropriate `ModelForm` subclass. Then to show a custom label on each checkbox, [create your own form field class derived from `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, and override `label_from_instance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). You may also add HTML tags to the string returned by `label_from_instance` to make it look as pretty as you want, but remember to wrap the returned string with [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).

```
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple
from django.forms.models import ModelMultipleChoiceField
...
class CustomSelectMultiple(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s: %s %s" %(obj.name, obj.short_description, obj.price)

class BarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo = CustomSelectMultiple(queryset=Foo.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        widgets = {"foo":CheckboxSelectMultiple(),}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. My mistake when I was translate my real model names to the foo/bar model names. Actually it's 'BarForm'. I just trying to use 'CheckboxSelectMultiple' and I have checkboxes with unicode names. How to get all objects data in template? Name, short_description and price with checkbox?

Comment: I've edited my answer to use correct class/variable names and also added info on how to customize the label on each checkbox (it would be good if you'd edit your question as well to avoid confusion). I hope it helps!

Comment: Seems that I'm lost Checkboxes in template using this code. Now I have all data but in select field, not as checkboxes. ` widgets = {"foo":CheckboxSelectMultiple(),} ` don't work anymore.

Comment: Fixed! I'm remove `widgets = {"foo":CheckboxSelectMultiple(),}` line and change `foo = CustomSelectMultiple(queryset=Foo.objects.all())` to `foo = CustomSelectMultiple(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Foo.objects.all())` thanks to Yuji Tomita comment. Thanks!

Comment: I tried all these suggestions but no joy! Tried in Django: 1.5.4